# Using Snappy compression in Spark in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: java, docker, google-kubernetes-engine, snappy

I have a service running in a Docker container in the Google Kubernetes Engine
It writes data to Google Cloud Storage, storing it as an .avro file using Snappy compression.

```
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", true)
conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec")
```

It works great. Then I set up a new project, deployed it to a new container and it didn't work, the service and the Docker file is the same but I'm getting this error:

```
 org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
```

at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78) 
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) 
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109) 
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)  ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy 
 at org.apache.avro.file.SnappyCodec.compress(SnappyCodec.java:43) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream$DataBlock.compressUsing(DataFileStream.java:358) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeBlock(DataFileWriter.java:382) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.sync(DataFileWriter.java:401) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.flush(DataFileWriter.java:410) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.close(DataFileWriter.java:433) 
 at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.close(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:83) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.closeWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:361) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:137) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127) 
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139) ... 8 more Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy 
 at org.apache.avro.file.SnappyCodec.compress(SnappyCodec.java:43) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream$DataBlock.compressUsing(DataFileStream.java:358) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeBlock(DataFileWriter.java:382) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.sync(DataFileWriter.java:401) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.flush(DataFileWriter.java:410) 
 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.close(DataFileWriter.java:433) 
 at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.close(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:83) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.closeWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:361) 
 at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:142) 
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1424)

Odd. 
The snappy jar file is still present in the Docker image - so I don't know why the service can't load the class.

It works if I disable compression (which is not ideal). 
Perhaps the compression libraries supported by Google Cloud Storage have changed? Any suggestions? (I'm open to other compression libraries)

Comment: It could be a GCS permissions issue but it’s hard to tell just from the logs. 
Saying this, GCP storage docs propose gzip. [1] for transcoding.

Maybe  you will  have better luck with that.

The doc is for BigQuery but you can also look at how they are  loading Avro data from Cloud Storage as a reference [2] to see if anything was missed.

If you get this to work, it’d be great to know what you did. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding 
[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue, but not in a bare metal kubernetes cluster and without GCP/GCS involved.

What version of spark are you running? How did you build the docker image?

Comment: I think I found the issue. It seems to be a problem with the alpine:8-alpine docker image. I switched it to `openjdk:8u151-alpine` and it mysteriously started working. You also need to remove the line `apk upgrade` because it updates the Java version